# How is the TeX manuscript `\iftrue\expandafter a\else b\fi c\bye` processed?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, expansion

Could someone please tell me if my understanding of how a TeX engine, such as `tex` or `pdftex`, processes the following TeX manuscript is correct, and, if not, set me straight?

```
\iftrue\expandafter a\else b\fi c\bye
```

The difficulty arises in understanding how `\else` is expanded, and whether `\fi` remains on the input stream when the `\else` clause is consumed.

My interest in this form is due to my coming across a similar form in the TikZ source code (in the file `<pgf installation dir>/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`):

```
\def\tikz@endscope{%
    \iftikz@auto@end@path%
        \expandafter\tikz@finish\expandafter\egroup%
        \else\expandafter\tikz@@endscope%
    \fi%
}
```

---

Here's how a TeX engine processes the TeX manuscript

```
\iftrue\expandafter a\else b\fi c\bye
```

1. The control sequence `\iftrue` is removed from the input stream, and an internal flag is pushed onto a stack, which I will call *the `if` stack*, to indicate we are inside the `true`-clause of a conditional expression.
2. `\expandafter` expands as follows:

   1. The control sequence `\expandafter` is removed from the input stream.
   2. The token at the beginning of the input stream, namely `a`, is removed from the input stream and pushed on an internal stack that I will call *the `expand after` stack*.
   3. The token at the beginning of the input stream, namely `\else`, is expanded. Now, how does an `\else` expand? According to the TeX Book (20th printing, 1991, p. 213):

      > when `\else`, `\or`, or `\fi` is expanded, TEX reads to the end of any text that ought to be skipped.

      So TeX skips, i.e. drops from the input stream, everything between the `\else`, including the `\else`, and the first `\fi`, not including the `\fi`. This leaves the input stream with the following contents:

      ```
      \fi c\bye
      ```
   4. The `expand after` stack is popped and its elements are prepended to the beginning of the input stream. So at the end of this step, the input stream consists of the following:

      ```
      a\fi c\bye
      ```
   5. Normal TeX processing resumes.
3. The letter `a` is written to the dvi file.
4. The `\fi` pops the `if` stack (recall step 1). The `if` stack is now empty, so TeX knows we're no longer inside a conditional.
5. The letter `c` is written to the dvi file.
6. The engine stops.

In the end, the dvi file contains the text

> ac

Comment: Not sure what you are after as an answer here, but you've got the `\fi` business wrong: it's been removed by the expansion of `\else`. That's important where `a` consumes the next token ...

Comment: @JosephWright: Your comment is precisely the kind of answer I was hoping for, though I would appreciate it if you can elaborate on this, because, if the `\fi` is removed by the expansion of `\else`, then shouldn't the engine complain at the end of the manuscript about an unclosed `\if`?

Comment: Well finding `\else`  means that the conditional has ended and TeX is simply 'tidying up', so there is naturally not error.

Comment: @JosephWright: I see. And how can you be sure that this is how things work, rather than the way I described? Is there a way to tell the two interpretations apart?

Comment: Try replacing `a` by for example `\show` ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a series of expandable commands. Her, I'm going to largely focus on how things happen from a 'TeX macro point-of-view': there is of course detail in TeX-the-program but my understanding is that is not the focus.

First, TeX expands `\iftrue` which increases the conditional counter by one but does nothing else. TeX then finds `\expandafter`, which skips over the `a` (as you say putting on a stack) and expands `\else`. The result is that TeX looks for a matching `\fi`, so examines but does not expand tokens until it finds one, discarding the material it collects on the way. Once it finds `\fi` (or something `\let` to the primitive), the conditional counter is decreased and the `\fi` is also discarded. At this stage the `a` is reinserted and we (effectively) have

```
ac\bye
```

This is typeset in the usual way.

The fact that expansion of a conditional *removes* it is important. It means that in combination with `\expandafter` the conditional can be closed *before* the 'payload' is expanded. You can see that in a construct such as

```
\iftrue\expandafter\show\else b\fi c\bye
```

where you will get

```
> the letter c.
l.1 \iftrue\expandafter \show\else b\fi c
                                         \bye
```

That is vital if you are looking to insert anything taking an argument: you'd otherwise have to contend with stray conditional ends everywhere.